# Como resolver produto escalar sem usar a biblioteca numpy (python)

Tags: python, array, matemática

Olá, eu estou tentando fazer essa operação sem usar a biblioteca Numpy, coisa que por si só já é uma tragédia.

Eu recebo do usuário dois vetores de tamanhos iguais, e preciso fazer a operação de produto escalar entre eles. Lembrando que produto escalar é **a.b = a1.b1 + a2.b2 .... + an.bn**

Acho que está faltando alguma coisa que eu não entendi completamente...

Por exemplo, se eu colocar o vetor A como [1, 2, 3] e o vetor B como [3, 2, 1], o resultado da multiplicação entre eles **deveria** ser vetor C = [3, 4, 3]. Mas do jeito que esse código foi escrito **o que eu tenho é**: [3, 2, 1, 6, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3] Como eu não estou conseguindo nem multiplicar os elementos dos vetores, não faz nem sentido tentar somar os elementos do vetor C, para obter o produto final.
segue o código:

```
vetorA = []
vetorB = []

numA = int(input('Digite o tamanho do vetor do A: '))
while len(vetorA) < numA:
    vetorA.append(int(input('Digite um numero para preencher o vetor A: ')))

numB = int(input('Digite o tamanho do vetor do B: '))
while len(vetorB) < numB:
    vetorB.append(int(input('Digite um numero para preencher o vetor B: ')))

if len(vetorA) == len(vetorB):
    vetorC = []
    for itemA in vetorA:
        for itemB in vetorB:
            new = itemA * itemB
            vetorC.append(new)
    print(vetorC)
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que as soluções sugeridas (tanto abaixo quando na duplicada sugerida no bloco azul acima) só funcionam se as listas tiverem o mesmo tamanho, pois `zip` se encerra assim que a menor delas terminar. Se for processar listas de tamanhos diferentes, teria que usar [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar uma compreensão de lista:

```
vetorC = [elemA * elemB for elemA, elemB in zip(vetorA, vetorB)]
```

---

A função `zip` retorna os elementos do `vetorA` e `vetorB` em paralelo para cada iteração, então

```
list(zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]))
```

retorna

```py
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Já a compreensão de lista cria uma lista construindo um item para cada iteração. Nesse caso, o item a ser construído é o valor `elemA * elemB`. [Na documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) existe uma explicação explicando e demonstrando o uso de compreensões de lista.

Comment: Boaa, vou testar aqui.

Comment: Esse zip eu ainda não conhecia...

Comment: Sim! Você pode consultar sua documentação [aqui](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#zip) e ver mais funções semelhantes.

Comment: Funcionou aqui! Eu só não tenho certza se entendi esse trecho "elemA * elemB for elemA, elemB "

Comment: Editei minha resposta com um link explicando como funciona.

Comment: Obrigada, ajudou bastante!